# MySQL Create Table doesn't work

Tags: mysql, plugins, bukkit

can you help me with MySQL? I tried to make some Plugins for Bukkit but my newest plugin can't create tables in MySQL. The Server crashes everytime (it loads the plugin but then nothing happens anymore) and i don't know why...

```
String tablename = "Test";
String request = "Spielername VARCHAR(100), Testvalue VARCHAR(100)";
con.createStatement().executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tablename+" ("+request+")");
```

Thats the line in the Crash-Log.
It would be nice if you could help me.
Sry 4 bad english, i'm german :D

//--------
German:
Hey, Ich habe ein Problem... Jedes mal wenn Ich über ein Bukkit Plugin eine Datenbank Tabelle erstelle, hört der Server auf zu reagieren. Er lädt immer bis zu dem Punkt, ab dem er die Tabelle erstellen soll und lädt dann nicht mehr weiter.
Nachdem Ich den Server stoppe steht in den Crash-Logs dass folgende Zeile fehlerhaft wäre:

```
String tablename = "Test";
String request = "Spielername VARCHAR(100), Testvalue VARCHAR(100)";
con.createStatement().executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tablename+" ("+request+")");
```

Bisher hat diese aber immer funktioniert und beim debuggen wird auch ausgegeben, dass der Server mit der Datenbank verbunden ist.

//Additional Information (Stacktrace):
    ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
    // I just don't know what went wrong :(

```
Time: 4/15/16 3:36 PM
Description: Watching Server

java.lang.Error
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2979)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2968)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3516)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2620)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1662)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1581)
    at mysqllib.MySQL.createTable(MySQL.java:65)
    at mysqllib.LibClass.<init>(LibClass.java:6)
    at mysqllib.RankLib.<init>(RankLib.java:17)
    at mysqllib.Main.onEnable(Main.java:48)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:332)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:404)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:341)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:313)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:721)
    at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:543)
    at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25)
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:140)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:621)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:607)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.aO(DedicatedServer.java:371)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:336)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:632)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2979)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2968)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3516)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2620)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1662)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1581)
    at mysqllib.MySQL.createTable(MySQL.java:65)
    at mysqllib.Main.onEnable(Main.java:48)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:332)
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:404)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:341)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:313)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:721)
    at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:543)
    at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25)
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:140)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:621)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:607)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.aO(DedicatedServer.java:371)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:336)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:632)

-- Thread Dump --
Details:
    Threads: "Timer-2" Id=97 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.TaskQueue@66be0ec4
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.TaskQueue@66be0ec4
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)


"pool-46-thread-1" Id=96 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@6879ec63
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@6879ec63
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ...


"EbeanCacheWarmer" Id=95 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory$CacheWarmer.run(DefaultServerFactory.java:509)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)


"pool-26-thread-2" Id=93 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@6c4665b4
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@6c4665b4
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ...


"pool-29-thread-2" Id=92 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2944e658
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2944e658
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ...


"Netty Epoll Server IO #4" Id=26 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:194)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:219)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #3" Id=25 RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:194)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:219)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #2" Id=24 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:194)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:219)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"pool-4-thread-1" Id=91 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@3f9a059a
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@3f9a059a
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #1" Id=23 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:194)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:219)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"File IO Thread" Id=90 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.FileIOThread.c(SourceFile:51)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.FileIOThread.run(SourceFile:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"Server Watchdog" Id=71 RUNNABLE
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method)
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:454)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ThreadWatchdog.run(SourceFile:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"Timer-1" Id=59 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.TaskQueue@1827ecfe
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.TaskQueue@1827ecfe
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)


"Timer-0" Id=55 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.TaskQueue@4713518b
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.TaskQueue@4713518b
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)


"pool-8-thread-1" Id=54 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@496b1917
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@496b1917
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ...


"Ebean-TeleportSigns.0" Id=51 WAITING on java.lang.Object@26326375
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.Object@26326375
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.thread.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:75)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"EbeanBackgroundThread" Id=50 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread$Runner.run(BackgroundThread.java:168)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"Java2D Disposer" Id=47 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@1d53b51
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@1d53b51
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #0" Id=22 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:194)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:219)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"Server console handler" Id=18 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    -  locked java.io.BufferedInputStream@5c17bde9
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:248)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:261)
    -  locked org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream@4d25a4dd
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:198)
    -  locked org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream@4d25a4dd
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readCharacter(ConsoleReader.java:2145)
    ...


"Thread-4" Id=19 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@78b94fc7
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@78b94fc7
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at com.mojang.util.QueueLogAppender.getNextLogEvent(QueueLogAppender.java:77)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.util.TerminalConsoleWriterThread.run(TerminalConsoleWriterThread.java:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"DestroyJavaVM" Id=17 RUNNABLE


"Server thread" Id=15 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
    -  locked com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream@509eec32
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    ...


"Server Infinisleeper" Id=16 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer$1.run(DedicatedServer.java:53)


"Snooper Timer" Id=12 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.TaskQueue@5164a28c
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.TaskQueue@5164a28c
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)


"Signal Dispatcher" Id=4 RUNNABLE


"Finalizer" Id=3 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@63910810
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@63910810
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)


"Reference Handler" Id=2 WAITING on java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@4449972c
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@4449972c
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)



Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ThreadWatchdog.run(SourceFile:59)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

*Edit:
//Full-Method

```
public static void createTable(){
        if(isConnected()){
            try {
                String tablename = "Test";
                String request = "Spielername VARCHAR(100), Testvalue VARCHAR(100)
                con.createStatement().executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tablename+" ("+request+")");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

onEnable code:

```
        createConfig(); //=> Works
        readConfig(); //=> Works
        MySQL.connect(); //System.out.println => message
        MySQL.createTable();
        System.out.println("[MySQL] Plugin enabled!"); //=> no message
```

There is no Exception... The server only stops loading

Comment: Try checking the syntax of a create statement! `String request = "( Spielername VARCHAR(100), Testvalue VARCHAR(100) )";`

Comment: Then of course it would be a good idea to check for errors after the `con.createStatement().....` code line

Answer (score 0):

You did not paste the exception, only the stacktrace.

### There could be more than one cause:

1. you need the right privileges
2. table Test already exists
3. maybe the sql executor wants the column_names like this `Testvalue`

Comment: excuse me @RiggsFolly but I see only the last ; INTO the query is missing.
The parentheses are already ok

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649445/mysql-create-table-doesnt-work#comment60892871_36649445 I think brackets are required around the column definitions And like you said, he should be using a try catch so he can look at and react to any exceptions thrown

Comment: There is no exception, the table doesn't exist (table & permissions checked via phpmyadmin) and the syntaxes worked for a long time... but it only fails since yesterday

Comment: @dragon if you put the resulting query in phpmyadmin, does it work ?

Comment: Yes it works but it only doesn't work when i do it with my plugin (MySQLConnectorJ in an external program works with the same code)...

Comment: @dragon 
Have you tried this tutorial ?
[link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-tables.htm)

It wraps into a try..catch block and separates the creation of the statement from the execution (to have different lines in the stacktrace). Try that and then re-paste the stacktrace (if still not works)

Comment: Thanks for the help :D after adding Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); it works :-)